# Is it possible to execute sh files GUI application from linux remote server and view it on local machine?

Tags: linux, windows, putty, winscp, denodo

I have a job that runs denodo platform on remote server. Sh files is a GUI application, and I have to run it to start denodo service. I can't access it in windows, is there a way to solve these problems?

Already running sh files on Putty Windows, but only return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a linux GUI application, you should "export display" to view the server screen on your workstation.

Depending of your workstation linux distribution, it might be as easy as :

```
xhost +<IP_address_of_workstation>
./runMyApp.sh
```

As your workstation is running windows operating system, you have do further configuration : 
https://superuser.com/questions/325630/how-can-i-export-display-from-a-linux-terminal-to-a-windows-pc
https://seanthegeek.net/234/graphical-linux-applications-bash-ubuntu-windows/

If your workstation is connected through **SSH** you need even more configuration as discussed here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely

Answer (score 0):

You can run GUI-Applications of remote linux host in a windows client via ssh (putty) with x-forwarding and an installed x-server (xming)

See this question:
https://superuser.com/questions/299158/how-to-make-putty-do-the-equivalent-of-ssh-x